# XML-сериализация по особым правилам

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Имеется электронный документооборот. Обмен данными выполняется с помощью XML следующей структуры:

```
<document>
    <tag1 value="1"/>
    <tag2 value="text"/>
    <tag3 value="01.01.2017 10:20:15"/>
    <tag4 value="2"/>
    <tag5 value="02.02.2017 20:30:45"/>
    <tag6 value="text too"/>
    <tag7 value="3.5"/>
    <outerTag1>
        <innerTag11 value="5"/>
        <innerTag12 value="some text"/>
        <innerTag13 value="some text"/>
        <innerTag14 value="7"/>
        <innerTag15 value="8"/>
        <innerTag16 value="6"/>
        <innerOuterTag11>
            <innerInnerTag111 value="text"/>
            <innerInnerTag112 value="03.03.2017 03:03:03"/>
        </innerOuterTag11>
    </outerTag1>
    <outerTag2>
        <innerTag21 value="text"/>
        <innerTag22 value="text"/>
        <innerTag23 value="text"/>
        <innerTag24 value="text"/>
        <innerTag25 value="text"/>
        <innerTag26 value="text"/>
    </outerTag2>
</document>
```

Проблема на лицо - требуется куча классов примерно такой структуры:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="tag1")]
public class Tag1
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

и потом:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="document")]
public class Document
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag1")]
    public Tag1 Tag1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag2")]
    public Tag2 Tag2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag3")]
    public Tag3 Tag3 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag4")]
    public Tag4 Tag4 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag5")]
    public Tag5 Tag5 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag6")]
    public Tag6 Tag6 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag7")]
    public Tag7 Tag7 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="outerTag1")]
    public OuterTag1 OuterTag1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="outerTag2")]
    public OuterTag2 OuterTag2 { get; set; }
}
```

Хотелось бы вместо этого написать класс со свойствами простых типов:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="document")]
public class Document
{
    [...(ElementName="tag1")]
    public int Tag1 { get; set; }
    [...(ElementName="tag2")]
    public string Tag2 { get; set; }
    [...(ElementName="tag3")]
    public DateTime Tag3 { get; set; }
    [...(ElementName="tag4")]
    public int Tag4 { get; set; }
    [...(ElementName="tag5")]
    public DateTime Tag5 { get; set; }
    [...(ElementName="tag6")]
    public string Tag6 { get; set; }
    [...(ElementName="tag7")]
    public decimal Tag7 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="outerTag1")]
    public OuterTag1 OuterTag1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="outerTag2")]
    public OuterTag2 OuterTag2 { get; set; }
}
```

и не плодить кучу мелких классов типа `Tag1`, `Tag2`, ...

Можно ли как-то это сделать? В идеале хотелось бы сделать кастомный атрибут `MyXmlElement` и использовать его вместо `XmlElement`, но как научить `XmlSerializer` понимать его и генерировать соответствующую разметку? Или может есть какой-то другой способ?

Comment: Так или иначе, логику чтения/записи придётся писать вручную. Это можно сделать с помощью Linq2Xml или реализовав интерфейс `IXmlSerializable` или создав кастомные `XmlReader` и `XmlWriter`. Кастомный атрибут [можно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45735169/5045688) сделать, но `XmlSerializer` его не будет учитывать. Придётся в ридере/райтере его обрабатывать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, пока думаю над этим. Наверное надо создавать какой-то базовый класс, реализующий `IXmlSerializable`, который будет проверять соответствующий атрибут. А все мои классы наследовать от него.

Comment: Вместо ручного переписывания, рекомендую подумать над вариантом - скачать исходники сериализатора от MS, и сделать свой форк. Это будет быстрее и удобнее. Аналогичное мне приходилось делать с Generic коллекциями.

Comment: А в чём проблема с мелкими классами? Они ж не мешают? Можно написать плоский класс для работы с документом, и мелкие классы для сериализации.

Comment: @VladD, проблема в том, что их будет пару сотен. И каждый раз вместо `Tag2 = "text"` надо писать `Tag2 = new Tag2 { Value = "text" }`

Comment: @Андрей: Ну, это разбиение в любом случае _где-то_ должно быть. Один раз можно сделать. Я бы просто написал кодогенератор, который бы генерировал плоский класс, мелкие классы для разбиения, и конвертирующую функцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отказался от реализации интерфейса `IXmlSerializable` - решение получалось очень громоздким и не красивым, к тому же нужно учесть много всевозможных нюансов, которые учтены в штатной работе сериализатора.

В итоге написал простой класс:

```
public class Tag<T>
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "value")]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => Value.ToString();

    public static implicit operator Tag<T>(T value) => new Tag<T> { Value = value };
    public static implicit operator T(Tag<T> tag) => tag.Value;
}
```

Это позволило выбросить кучу мелких классов `Tag1`, `Tag2` и т.д. Сам документ принял вид:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="document")]
public class Document
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag1")]
    public Tag<int> Tag1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag2")]
    public Tag<string> Tag2 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag3")]
    public Tag<DateTime> Tag3 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag4")]
    public Tag<int> Tag4 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag5")]
    public Tag<DateTime> Tag5 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag6")]
    public Tag<string> Tag6 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="tag7")]
    public Tag<decimal> Tag7 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="outerTag1")]
    public OuterTag1 OuterTag1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="outerTag2")]
    public OuterTag2 OuterTag2 { get; set; }
}
```

Ну и благодаря операторам для неявного приведения типов документ создается так же просто:

```
var doc = new Document
{
    Tag1 = 1,
    Tag2 = "text",
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

А давайте сделаем кодогенерацию? Т4 прекрасно подходит. Мы создадим два класса: один со вложенными классами для сериализации, и другой плоский, с которым легко и удобно работать. И конвертирующие функции.

Генерировать будем на основе вот такого XML-документа (я положил его в проект под названием DocumentProto.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<document>
  <tag1 type="int"/>
  <tag2 type="string"/>
  <tag3 type="DateTime"/>
  <tag4 type="int"/>
  <tag5 type="DateTime"/>
  <tag6 type="string"/>
  <tag7 type="double"/>
  <outerTag1>
    <innerTag11 type="int"/>
    <innerTag12 type="string"/>
    <innerTag13 type="string"/>
    <innerTag14 type="int"/>
    <innerTag15 type="int"/>
    <innerTag16 type="int"/>
    <innerOuterTag11>
      <innerInnerTag111 type="string"/>
      <innerInnerTag112 type="DateTime"/>
    </innerOuterTag11>
  </outerTag1>
  <outerTag2>
    <innerTag21 type="string"/>
    <innerTag22 type="string"/>
    <innerTag23 type="string"/>
    <innerTag24 type="string"/>
    <innerTag25 type="string"/>
    <innerTag26 type="string"/>
  </outerTag2>
</document>
```

Кладём в проект новый файл типа T4 через Add New Item → Text Template (не Runtime TextTemplate!). Я назвал его Document.tt.

В первой строке меняем `hostspecific="false"` на `true`. Добавляем нужные сборки:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.Linq" #>
```

и

```
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Linq" #>
```

меняем `output extension` на `".cs"`.

Дальше дело техники: нам нужно распарсить XML.
Открываем документ, читаем его в память:

```
<#
    var xmlpath = Host.ResolvePath("DocumentProto.xml");
    XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);
#>
```

Создаём шаблон файла:

```
// Generated code! Do not edit!

using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace CodegenTest
{
    // будем добавлять тут
}
```

Теперь, генерация набора классов для сериализации. Пишем (предварительно отладив это на тестовом приложении командной строки) в конце tt-файла:

```
<#+
    void GenerateNestedClasses(XElement element)
    {
        var childClasses = new Queue<XElement>();
        string className = element.Name.LocalName;
        string capitalizedClassName = char.ToUpper(className[0]) + className.Substring(1);
        WriteLine($"[XmlRoot(ElementName=\"{className}\")]");
        WriteLine($"class {capitalizedClassName}");
        WriteLine("{");
        foreach (var sub in element.Elements())
        {
            string type;
            string name = sub.Name.LocalName;
            string capitalizedName = char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
            if (!sub.HasAttributes) // nested class
            {
                type = capitalizedName;
                childClasses.Enqueue(sub);
            }
            else
            {
                type = (string)sub.Attribute("type");
            }

            WriteLine($"    [XmlElement(ElementName=\"{name}\")]");
            WriteLine($"    public {type} {capitalizedName} {{ get; set; }}");
        }
        WriteLine("}");
        WriteLine("");

        foreach (var child in childClasses)
            GenerateNestedClasses(child);
    }

#>
```

(Внутри тегов `<#+ #>` располагаются дополнительные методы для генерации.)

Пользуемся:

```
    namespace Serialization
    {
<#
    PushIndent("        ");
    GenerateNestedClasses(xd.Root);
    ClearIndent();
#>
    }
```

Получаем в Document.cs:

```
namespace Serialization
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName="document")]
    class Document
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="tag1")]
        public int Tag1 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="tag2")]
        public string Tag2 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="tag3")]
        public DateTime Tag3 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="tag4")]
        public int Tag4 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="tag5")]
        public DateTime Tag5 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="tag6")]
        public string Tag6 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="tag7")]
        public double Tag7 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="outerTag1")]
        public OuterTag1 OuterTag1 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="outerTag2")]
        public OuterTag2 OuterTag2 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="outerTag1")]
    class OuterTag1
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag11")]
        public int InnerTag11 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag12")]
        public string InnerTag12 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag13")]
        public string InnerTag13 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag14")]
        public int InnerTag14 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag15")]
        public int InnerTag15 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag16")]
        public int InnerTag16 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerOuterTag11")]
        public InnerOuterTag11 InnerOuterTag11 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="innerOuterTag11")]
    class InnerOuterTag11
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerInnerTag111")]
        public string InnerInnerTag111 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerInnerTag112")]
        public DateTime InnerInnerTag112 { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="outerTag2")]
    class OuterTag2
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag21")]
        public string InnerTag21 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag22")]
        public string InnerTag22 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag23")]
        public string InnerTag23 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag24")]
        public string InnerTag24 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag25")]
        public string InnerTag25 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag26")]
        public string InnerTag26 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Добавляем ещё в конец файла генерацию свойств «плоского класса»:

```
void GenerateFlatClassProps(XElement element)
{
    foreach (var sub in element.Elements())
    {
        if (!sub.HasAttributes) // nested
            GenerateFlatClassProps(sub);
        else
        {
            var type = (string)sub.Attribute("type");
            string name = sub.Name.LocalName;
            string capitalizedName = char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
            WriteLine($"public {type} {capitalizedName} {{ get; set; }}");
        }
    }
}
```

и метода чтения свойств в плоский класс:

```
void GenerateFlatteningBody(XElement element, string path)
{
    string name = element.Name.LocalName;
    string capitalizedName = char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
    foreach (var sub in element.Elements())
    {
        string subName = sub.Name.LocalName;
        string capitalizedSubName = char.ToUpper(subName[0]) + subName.Substring(1);
        if (!sub.HasAttributes) // nested
            GenerateFlatteningBody(sub, path + "." + capitalizedSubName);
        else
            WriteLine($"this.{capitalizedSubName} = that{path}.{capitalizedSubName};");
    }
}
```

Пользуемся ими наверху:

```
    public class Document
    {
<#
    PushIndent("        ");
    GenerateFlatClassProps(xd.Root);
    ClearIndent();
#>
        private void AssignFromSerialized(Serialization.Document that)
        {
<#
    PushIndent("            ");
    GenerateFlatteningBody(xd.Root, "");
    ClearIndent();
#>
        }

        internal static Document FromSerialized(Serialization.Document sdoc)
        {
            var doc = new Document();
            doc.AssignFromSerialized(sdoc);
            return doc;
        }
    }
```

Получаем готовый сгенерированный набор классов для использования:

```
namespace CodegenTest
{

    public class Document
    {
        public int Tag1 { get; set; }
        public string Tag2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Tag3 { get; set; }
        public int Tag4 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Tag5 { get; set; }
        // ...
        private void AssignFromSerialized(Serialization.Document that)
        {
            this.Tag1 = that.Tag1;
            this.Tag2 = that.Tag2;
            // ...
            this.InnerTag11 = that.OuterTag1.InnerTag11;
            this.InnerTag12 = that.OuterTag1.InnerTag12;
            this.InnerTag13 = that.OuterTag1.InnerTag13;
            this.InnerTag14 = that.OuterTag1.InnerTag14;
            this.InnerTag15 = that.OuterTag1.InnerTag15;
            this.InnerTag16 = that.OuterTag1.InnerTag16;
            this.InnerInnerTag111 = that.OuterTag1.InnerOuterTag11.InnerInnerTag111;
            // ...
        }

        internal static Document FromSerialized(Serialization.Document sdoc)
        {
            var doc = new Document();
            doc.AssignFromSerialized(sdoc);
            return doc;
        }
    }

    namespace Serialization
    {
        [XmlRoot(ElementName="document")]
        class Document
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName="tag1")]
            public int Tag1 { get; set; }
            // ...
            [XmlElement(ElementName="outerTag1")]
            public OuterTag1 OuterTag1 { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName="outerTag2")]
            public OuterTag2 OuterTag2 { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName="outerTag1")]
        class OuterTag1
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag11")]
            public int InnerTag11 { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName="innerTag12")]
            public string InnerTag12 { get; set; }
            // ...
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Обновление: исправил `GenerateNestedClasses` на такое:

```
void GenerateNestedClasses(XElement element)
{
    var childClasses = new Queue<XElement>();
    var leafClasses = new Queue<XElement>();
    string className = element.Name.LocalName;
    string capitalizedClassName = char.ToUpper(className[0]) + className.Substring(1);
    WriteLine($"[XmlRoot(ElementName=\"{className}\")]");
    WriteLine($"class {capitalizedClassName}");
    WriteLine("{");
    foreach (var sub in element.Elements())
    {
        string name = sub.Name.LocalName;
        string capitalizedName = char.ToUpper(name[0]) + name.Substring(1);
        if (!sub.HasAttributes) // nested class
            childClasses.Enqueue(sub);
        else
            leafClasses.Enqueue(sub);

        WriteLine($"    [XmlElement(ElementName=\"{name}\")]");
        WriteLine($"    public {capitalizedName} {capitalizedName} {{ get; set; }}");
    }
    WriteLine("}");
    WriteLine("");

    foreach (var leaf in leafClasses)
        GenerateLeafClass(leaf);
    foreach (var child in childClasses)
        GenerateNestedClasses(child);
}

void GenerateLeafClass(XElement element)
{
    string className = element.Name.LocalName;
    string capitalizedClassName = char.ToUpper(className[0]) + className.Substring(1);
    string type = (string)element.Attribute("type");
    WriteLine($"class {capitalizedClassName}");
    WriteLine("{");
    WriteLine($"    [XmlAttribute]");
    WriteLine($"    public {type} Value {{ get; set; }}");
    WriteLine("}");
    WriteLine("");
}
```

и в `GenerateFlatteningBody` последнюю строчку на

```
WriteLine($"this.{capitalizedSubName} = that{path}.{capitalizedSubName}.Value;");
```

Получились промежуточные классы вида

```
class Tag1
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

На всякий случай, полный код tt-шаблона и сгенерированного результата: https://gist.github.com/vladd/7f25e0ceb625372bffdbf9b455452ae1

Comment: Только в `Serialization` должно быть не `public int Tag1 { get; set; }`, а `public Tag1 Tag1 { get; set; }`, где `Tag1` - ещё один класс со свойством `Value`, помеченным атрибутом `XmlAttribute`

Comment: @Андрей: То есть нужно, получается, две очереди?

Comment: `public int Tag1 { get; set; }` будет сериализовано в `<tag1>1</tag1>`, а мне нужно `<tag1 value="1" />`

Comment: @Андрей: Ага, понял. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Идея с кодогенерацией хорошая, надо обдумать как лучше воспользоваться. Плоский класс мне не совсем подходит, т.к. нет гарантии, что на разных уровнях не будет тегов с одинаковыми названиями, ну и плюс будет куча коллекций в документе. Пока думаю нагенерировать во все мелкие классы оператор для неявного преобразования, например `int` в `Tag1`. Или вообще взять что-то такое: https://pastebin.com/H47ee2Wa Что думаете об этом?

Comment: @Андрей: Почему бы и нет? Выглядит неплохо.